# No Activity found to handle Intent when trying to programmatically ask for permissions

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-manifest, android-permissions

I need to get the `MANAGE_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION` to be able to download and install APK's from my application. 
When I was targeting SDK 27 and lower, everything worked fine, when I declared

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

in the manifest and asked for permission with             `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 100);`

But now I need to target SDK 30, meaning that `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` is deprecated and not working for API versions 29 and 30.

I have been trying to find a workaround and one that I could think of was starting the `Intent` to allow users to switch the permission on by themselves but I cannot get it to work.

The code I am using:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
    try {
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("package:" + BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION, uri);
        startActivity(intent);
    } catch (Exception ex){
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
} else {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
            new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
            100);
}
```

And the error that I get when trying to open intent:

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.settings.MANAGE_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION }
```

The error comes from the catch block but the `Exception ex` gives the same error.

What am I doing wrong or is this just not allowed on the current phone I am using (XCover 4s Android 10).

Comment: `catch (Exception ex)` You are not printing the stack trace nor logging ex.getMessage(). So what do you know?

Comment: `the error that I get when trying to open intent:` That is while trying the second intent.

Comment: `need to get the MANAGE_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION to be able to download and install APK's from my application.` I doubt that. You can do such things without i think.

Comment: `I am using (XCover 4s).` But not telling Android version of that device.

Comment: Generally speaking, there is no requirement for a device manufacturer to support all possible `Settings` `Intent` actions. So, my guess is that your device lacks support for those all-files permissions `Intent` actions.

Comment: @blackapps Well I do need the permission, I have tried basically all the other ways around that, that I could think of. About my device, its like I mentioned.. If I try a device with Android 6, 7, 8, 9 everything works but when I try it with Android 10 or 11 I get the error I was mentioning. Also about the exception that I am not printing.. I have tried printing it and it is exactly the same: `android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.settings.MANAGE_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION }`

Comment: @CommonsWare So does that mean that there is no way around this?

Comment: "So does that mean that there is no way around this?" -- I do not have a workaround for you, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to getting the storage permission that worked for me.

I had to change the `Manifest.permission. strings` so instead of what was written in the question I used.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
            activity,
            new String[]{
                    Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                    Manifest.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
            },
            1
    );
} else {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity,
            new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
            100);
}
```

Or similarly this could be used :

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
}

if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
}
```

Then to get the prompt to allow user to install `Apps from unkown sources` :

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    if (!activity.getPackageManager().canRequestPackageInstalls()) {
        activity.startActivityForResult(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_UNKNOWN_APP_SOURCES).setData(Uri.parse(String.format("package:%s", activity.getPackageName()))), 1234);
    } else {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem when I was trying to navigate the user to enable all files access permission on the app screen directly.

Solution for this one is to add the package name like this:

```
val storageIntent = Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION,
                    Uri.parse("package:$packageName"))
```